# How to change directory sort order only in the current Finder window?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

I can't stand how in one Finder window you set the files to be sorted by name, and then open another Finder window and need to sort by size, well it changes all Finder windows to the same thing. So you have to change your original Finder window again back to sort by name.

Is there a way to make it so that only the folders you're in at that time change when you sort? Instead of all Finder windows?

Comment: Your question title is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort order is per directory. If multiple windows show the same directory, changing one sort order changes all. However, this does not affect other folders.

Also, this has nothing to do with "file organization", it's the Finder's view preferences. And they cannot be changed the way you seem to want them.

Comment: Hmm, i opened up a file folder on the desktop as well as the mac hard drive folder. I changed the desktop folder and it changed the hard drive folder structure. Is there a way to make this independent?

Comment: @zm15 I don't have that problem, but I think it could be possible that you don't have write access to those folders and therefore cannot change their settings.

Comment: @zm15 does it only happen with these two specific folders, or also with folders in your user account's home directory?